# Compiling MariaDB C/C++ Connector on Windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, mariadb

I am trying to use MariaDB in my visual studio project, so after looking at the documentation, I installed MariaDB and downloaded the source code for the C/C++ connector.

I got the include folder linked to the project, so I am able to make calls to the functions there, but it won't build because the linker fails to find the function definitions (obviously).  I have looked all over and cannot find any solid directions on building the .lib files I need.  I have found two sources that say that I need to just build the mariadb_connector_c.sln, but that file does not exist in the source code that I got, nor does it exist on their Git repo: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c

The closest thing that I have found is the appveyor.yml file they provided, which contains the following: [Contents of YML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LQ7L.png)

Is there anybody out there who has done this before?  I can't find anything online or in the files they provided pertaining to this.

**UPDATE:**

I found the answer thanks to some of the replies.  I needed to run the source code through cmake in order to get the .sln that I could then build to get the .lib files I need to link to the project.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Only the two different languages C and C++. Pick one!

Comment: Looks like a CMake project. So compile it with CMake.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me for my lack of understanding about this, but what do I compile with cmake?  I can't compile a folder, don't I still need some kind of project file?

Comment: Here is the [full log](http://buildbot.askmonty.org/buildbot/builders/win-connector_c_3/builds/132/steps/build_package32/logs/stdio) of how the CI system builds it from the git clone, hopefully you'll find there what you're looking for.

Comment: This appears to be building that mariadb_connector_c.sln file that I described in the question...again, I don't have that anywhere, and I cannot locate it anywhere

Comment: Can you explain how you "run the source through cmake" so that this question helps others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a generic answer for any cmake project

- Install CMake. make sure cmake.exe is in PATH (Windows installer offers this option). Install Visual Studio, and make sure C/C++ compiler is installed
- start command line prompt
- Execute "cmake . &&  cmake --build ." in the command line prompt.

That#s it.